# Button TabIndex on imported Outlook form regions in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, outlook-addin, tabindex

I have OL&VS 2010. If I design a form region directly in VS, then the `FormRegion.Designer.cs` file will contain definitions like:

```
this.SomeButton = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
```

but if designed in OL and imported, the definitions are:

```
this.SomeButton = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlkCommandButton)GetFormRegionControl("SomeButton");
```

My problem is that a `System.Windows.Forms.Button` has a `TabIndex` property that I can programmatically set, but a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlkCommandButton` does not.

How can I change an `OlkCommandButton`'s `TabIndex`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to cast a `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.OlkCommandButton` to a `Microsoft.Vbe.Interop.Forms.Control` and access the element's `TabIndex` that way.

Edit - Confirmed: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rgregg/archive/2007/10/01/common-properties-on-outlook-controls.aspx